# Westend token getting via polkadot/api

Tags: polkadot-js, token, westend

Would you please advise if there is an alternative to Faucet to get WND - does Polkadot API help with it?

I went through API documentation and did not find any info, I'm glad to be wrong :)

Thank you for any information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does Polkadot API help with it?

**No.**

If the faucet functionality was implemented on Westend network, then this would be possible. But right now, there is no such functionality built into the chain.

You can request for WND tokens here https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-testnet-faucet/westend or via https://matrix.to/#/#westend_faucet:matrix.org

Comment: Thank you for confirmation! Faucet works perfectly for me